# Customize webpack plugins using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a React app using create-react-app but I want to add some plugins to webpack like:

- image-webpack-loader
- terser-webpack-plugin

and some others but I don't want to eject my app. Is there any other option I can use to add those plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to eject there are tools like [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) which let you override CRA's webpack config as well as other configs (babel, jest, ...).